# Tomcat can not working in eclipse with servlet. How can I fix it?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I try delete and refresh tomcat but it not work. Sometime I catch errors and I don't why.Thanks you

> Console

```
Mar 17, 2022 9:42:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 17, 2022 9:42:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
Mar 17, 2022 9:42:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

> Message error

```
'Starting Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost' has encountered aproblem.
Server Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost failed to start.
```

Comment: This needs far, far, more details to say anything useful. Start with the rest of the errors from the Console output.

Comment: I got this same error  so many times. With this error, I had two url pattern same in two servlet diffent. Thanks !